# Form edit with ArrayCollection

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

Quick explanation of the subject:

- A "Project" can have several "Activities"
- I had to create simultaneously as many "Activities" as needed (You click on a button "Add an activity" and you got a new line which means a new activity). I managed to do that by doing Collections on my fields.

Here's the code of the formBuilder :

```
namespace CoreBundle\Form\Type;

use CoreBundle\Entity\Activities;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CreateNewActivitiesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'aeAmount',
                CollectionType::class,
                array(
                    'entry_type'    => TextType::class,
                    'allow_add'     => true,
                    'allow_delete'  => true,
                    'label'         => 'Montant de l\'AE',
                    'label_attr'    => array(
                        'class'     => 'aeAmount visuallyhidden'
                    ),
                    'entry_options' => array(
                        'attr'      => array(
                            'placeholder'   => '80 000 €'
                        ),

                    ),
                    'required'      => true
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'amountSpent',
                CollectionType::class,
                array(
                    'entry_type'    => TextType::class,
                    'allow_add'     => true,
                    'allow_delete'  => true,
                    'label'         => 'RDP : ',
                    'label_attr'    => array(
                        'class'     => 'amountSpent visuallyhidden'
                    ),
                    'entry_options' => array(
                        'attr'      => array(
                            'placeholder'   => '35 000 €'
                        )
                    ),
                    'required'      => true,
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'afName',
                CollectionType::class,
                array(
                    'entry_type'    => TextType::class,
                    'allow_add'     => true,
                    'allow_delete'  => true,
                    'required'      => true,
                    'label'         => 'AF : ',
                    'label_attr'    => array(
                        'class'     => 'afName visuallyhidden',
                    ),
                    'entry_options' => array(
                        'attr'      => array(
                            'placeholder'   => 'AERT-496'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'year',
                CollectionType::class,
                array(
                    'entry_type'    => TextType::class,
                    'allow_delete'  => true,
                    'allow_add'     => true,
                    'required'      => true,
                    'entry_options' => array(
                        'attr'      => array(
                            'readonly'  => true
                        )
                    ),
                    'label'         => 'Année : ',
                    'label_attr'    => array(
                        'class'     => 'year visuallyhidden'
                    )
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CoreBundle\Entity\Activities'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'corebundle_collection_activities';
    }
}
```

(I know i can do this much shorter, but refactorisation will be later.)

So, this is currently working, with his associated controller to add my activities, here it is :

```
/**
     * @param integer $projectId
     * @param string $projectType
     * @param integer $rdId
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function createNewActivityAction($projectId, $projectType, $rdId)
    {
        $activity = new Activities();
        $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

        $form = $this->createForm(CreateNewActivitiesType::class, $activity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $rdAffiliated = $em->getRepository('CoreBundle:DecisionStatement')->findOneBy(['id' => $rdId]);

            $formData = $form->getData();
            $yearList = $formData->getYear();
            $aeAmountList = $formData->getAeAmount();
            $afNameList = $formData->getAfName();
            $amountSpentList = $formData->getAmountSpent();

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($yearList); $i++) {
                $yearDatetime = new DateTime($yearList[$i] . '-01-01 00:00:00');
                $existingActivity = $em->getRepository('CoreBundle:Activities')->getExistingActivityWithoutIdentifier(
                    $yearDatetime,
                    $rdAffiliated
                );

                if ($existingActivity) {
                    /**
                     * @var Activities $currentActivity
                     */
                    $currentActivity = $existingActivity[0];
                    $currentActivity->setAeAmount(
                        $currentActivity->getAeAmount() + $aeAmountList[$i]
                    );
                    $currentActivity->setAmountSpent(
                        $currentActivity->getAmountSpent() + $amountSpentList[$i]
                    );

                    $em->persist($currentActivity);
                } else {
                    $newActivity = new Activities();
                    $newActivity->setYear($yearDatetime)
                        ->setAeAmount($aeAmountList[$i])
                        ->setAfName($afNameList[$i])
                        ->setAmountSpent($amountSpentList[$i])
                        ->setAfReception(false)
                        ->setDecisionStatement($rdAffiliated)
                        ->setPeopleByMonth(0);

                    $em->persist($newActivity);
                }
            }

            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('rd_show_activities', array(
                'rdId'          => $rdId,
                'projectType'   => $projectType,
                'projectId'     => $projectId
            ));
        }

        return $this->render('@Core/html/13-edit-activite.html.twig', array(
            'page'                 => 'activities_creation',
            'createActivitiesForm' => $form->createView(),
            'projectParentId'      => $projectId,
            'projectParentType'    => $projectType,
            'rdId'                 => $rdId
        ));
    }
```

Here is also a screenshot from the var_dump when activities form is submitted :

[image: var_dump of activities]

But where's my problem begins, it is when I want to edit because my form is based on the entity "Activities". But I want to edit all the existing "Activities" for a given project, I'll have an array containing my "Activities" objects (found by the findBy method), so I can't pass my array into my form, which results in an error.
How to transform this array of many "Activities" objects into only one "Activities" object?

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the entities involved? It's far better to check for the mapping and knowing which class is on the inverse side of the relation.

Comment: @sentenza Body is limited to 30000 characters. I posted my entities below

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have only one object "Activities" that contains several collection.
You should create an object activities that contains several activities.
Each activity has only one attribute "year", "amountSpent"...
When you edit your object "ActivitieS" with the appropriate form you will be able to edit each activity linked with this object.

Comment: Well, it is the very first time i used Collections, so i probably did something wrong. Isn't this because each of my fields in the formBuilder are determined as Collections ?

Comment: You have a problem with your model. Your var_dump show something is not okey. You field "year" is an array whereas in your model it's a datetime....

Comment: I take the year and then transform it into a Datetime in my Controller, once the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

#### Embed a collection of forms

To correctly manage this kind of problem you need to build a [Collection of forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) in Symfony.

> 1. **A "Project" can have several "Activities"**
> 2. **I had to create simultaneously as many "Activities" as needed** [...]

At first you need to build a *Project* entity that will contain all the *Activities*  as a Doctrine ArrayCollection as you can see below:

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Entity/Project.php**</kbd>

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Project
{

    protected $activities;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->activities = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }
}
```

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Form/Type/ProjectType.php**</kbd>

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use AppBundle\Entity\Project;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class ProjectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ActivitiesType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Project::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Then you need to enable the user to dynamically add an Activity to a Project you need to make advantage of the `prototype` variable, using Twig and JavaScript.

Comment: " 'entry_type' => ActivitiesType::class," --> So, ActivitiesType::class is supposed to be another FormType which contains all my fields ?

Comment: Yes, correct. It is a `FormType` of the *Activity* Entity.

Comment: I think the best way to give you an exhaustive answer is to have an entity diagram or something similar to start with. I see several entities and sub-entities. It's not so simple to find a good solution without having a complete picture of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken into consideration all the comments that you made and decided to review the whole thing.

DecisionStatement.php :

- Added in the __construct() method a new ArrayCollection for the Activities affiliated for a given DecisionStatement.
- The method to return the Activities affiliated was already here.

documents = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->activitiesAffiliated = new ArrayCollection();
        }

```
/**
 * Get activitiesAffiliated
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getActivitiesAffiliated()
{
    return $this->activitiesAffiliated;
}
```

I've created a new FormType (DecisionStatementType.php), to have my Collection of forms :

```
use CoreBundle\Entity\DecisionStatement;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class DecisionStatementType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'activitiesAffiliated',
                CollectionType::class,
                array(
                    'entry_type'    => NewActivityType::class,
                    'allow_add'     => true,
                    'allow_delete'  => true
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => DecisionStatement::class
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'corebundle_collection_decisionstatement';
    }
}
```

And here is the "subForm", newActivityType.php :

```
use CoreBundle\Entity\Activities;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class NewActivityType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'aeAmount',
                TextType::class,
                array(
                    'label'         => 'Montant de l\'AE',
                    'label_attr'    => array(
                        'class'     => 'aeAmount visuallyhidden'
                    ),
                    'attr'      => array(
                        'placeholder'   => '80 000 €'
                    ),
                    'required'      => true
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'amountSpent',
                TextType::class,
                array(
                    'label'         => 'RDP : ',
                    'label_attr'    => array(
                        'class'     => 'amountSpent visuallyhidden'
                    ),
                    'attr'      => array(
                        'placeholder'   => '35 000 €'
                    ),
                    'required'      => true,
                )
            )
            ->add(
                'afName',
                TextType::class,
                array(
                    'required'      => true,
                    'label'         => 'AF : ',
                    'label_attr'    => array(
                        'class'     => 'afName visuallyhidden',
                    ),
                    'attr'      => array(
                        'placeholder'   => 'AERT-496'
                    )
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CoreBundle\Entity\Activities'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'corebundle_collection_activities';
    }
}
```

In my view's DOM, i have now this :

[FormCollection Data-Prototype in DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nll9l.png)

So, is this a bit cleaner ?